# Flutter "Rate my App" always requires a Review when using native dialog on Android

Tags: flutter

I'm using the 'Rate my App' package to ask for rates in my app. https://pub.dev/packages/rate_my_app

I'm using the same code shown in the package page, but i'm setting the 'ignoreNativeDialog' parameter to false in order to use the native API even in Android. But when the dialog appears on android always requires a review after a rate.

Is it any way to set the review to be optional?

[image: Review is required]

```
RateMyApp rateMyApp = RateMyApp(
  preferencesPrefix: 'rateMyApp_',
  minDays: 7,
  minLaunches: 10,
  remindDays: 7,
  remindLaunches: 10,
);

rateMyApp.init().then((_) {
  if (rateMyApp.shouldOpenDialog) {
    rateMyApp.showStarRateDialog(
      context,
      title: 'Rate this app',
      message: 'You like this app ? Then take a little bit of your time to leave a rating :',
      actionsBuilder: (context, stars) {
        return [
          FlatButton(
            child: Text('OK'),
            onPressed: () async {
              print('Thanks for the ' + (stars == null ? '0' : stars.round().toString()) + ' star(s) !');
              await rateMyApp.callEvent(RateMyAppEventType.rateButtonPressed);
              Navigator.pop<RateMyAppDialogButton>(context, RateMyAppDialogButton.rate);
            },
          ),
        ];
      },
      ignoreNativeDialog: false, // This is the one parameter i set to false
      dialogStyle: DialogStyle(
        titleAlign: TextAlign.center,
        messageAlign: TextAlign.center,
        messagePadding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20),
      ),
      starRatingOptions: StarRatingOptions(),
      onDismissed: () => rateMyApp.callEvent(RateMyAppEventType.laterButtonPressed),
    );
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now it's clear.

The review was required becouse I was using it on a registered tester account. I tested with another account and it worked fine.